# Star Control 2: What are the rules of Frungy?

Tags: video-games, star-control-2

In the sci-fi game [*Star Control 2*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Control_II), the aliens known as the *Zoq Fot Pik* frequently mentioned a game/sport called "Frungy" (which they called the "Sport of Kings").  Were any of the rules or any other aspects of Frungy ever revealed?

I'm pretty sure no aspects of Frungy were revealed through the Star Control 2 game dialogue, but I wonder if any aspects were revealed through interviews or online chats with the game developers Paul Reiche and Fred Ford?  I know Reiche and Ford sometimes chatted with SC2 fans and answered various questions about the game.

Also, what about the novel [*Star Control: Interbellum*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0761501967) (which came out after Star Control 2) and the sequel [*Star Control 3*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Control_3) game?  I know that both of those probably aren't considered canon by most Star Control fans, but I'm still curious if either of them mention Frungy.

Comment: @Richard Thanks for the video.  I take it this is from the 3DO version of the game, since the PC version doesn't have the alien voices.  I learned something new about Frungy - it's pronounced with a soft 'g', I had always pronounced it with a hard 'g'.

Comment: I felt that my answer was pretty comprehensive, with a quote from the game's makers. Is there anything else you'd like to see before considering an acceptance?

Answer (score 3):

**There are no rules. The game is merely a plot device.**

This [fan site](http://wiki.uqm.stack.nl/Mysteries_left_by_Star_Control_II#How_is_Frungy_played.3F) offers a wide selection of emails that were provided by the writers in response to various questions posed by players:

> Q: **How is Frungy played?**
>
> **[Fred Ford] -** *I think one of the reasons SC has endured is that Paul and I were conscious of hinting about things, but ultimately letting the
>   game-player use his or her imagination to fill in the picture. **Frungy
>   is the poster-boy for this technique.***